# Implementing memristor based chaotic circuit - Muthuswamy

Tags: memristor

I'm trying to simulate the circuit mentioned [here](http://harpgroup.org/muthuswamy/pubs/ImplementingMemristorBasedChaoticCircuits.pdf) with LTspice IV by using opamp models below. V1 to V2 output should look like Chua's chaotic circuit (two scrolls connected to each other) but it's nowhere near that. I can't find out why. Could you help me?

Circuit:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Output of circuit as built:

[image]

Spice circuit:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 112 -208 -176 -208
WIRE 176 -208 112 -208
WIRE -240 -192 -656 -192
WIRE 176 -160 176 -208
WIRE 80 -96 80 -112
WIRE 80 -96 48 -96
WIRE -528 -80 -624 -80
WIRE -480 -80 -528 -80
WIRE -320 -80 -400 -80
WIRE -240 -80 -240 -192
WIRE -240 -80 -320 -80
WIRE -624 -48 -624 -80
WIRE -176 -48 -176 -208
WIRE 32 -48 32 -112
WIRE 32 -48 16 -48
WIRE 512 -48 512 -96
WIRE 624 -48 624 -96
WIRE -528 -32 -528 -80
WIRE -320 -32 -320 -80
WIRE -80 -32 -128 -32
WIRE 48 -16 48 -96
WIRE 48 -16 16 -16
WIRE -80 0 -96 0
WIRE 112 16 112 -208
WIRE 112 16 16 16
WIRE 176 32 176 -80
WIRE 176 32 32 32
WIRE -96 64 -96 0
WIRE 32 64 32 32
WIRE 32 64 -96 64
WIRE 176 64 176 32
WIRE 192 64 176 64
WIRE 288 64 272 64
WIRE -240 80 -240 -80
WIRE -176 80 -176 32
WIRE -176 80 -240 80
WIRE -128 80 -128 -32
WIRE -128 80 -176 80
WIRE 160 80 -48 80
WIRE 512 80 512 32
WIRE 624 80 624 32
WIRE -624 96 -624 32
WIRE -528 96 -528 32
WIRE -320 96 -320 32
WIRE 288 112 288 64
WIRE 288 112 -16 112
WIRE -48 128 -48 80
WIRE -16 128 -16 112
WIRE -304 144 -336 144
WIRE -224 144 -240 144
WIRE 288 192 288 112
WIRE -224 208 -224 144
WIRE -176 208 -224 208
WIRE -128 208 -128 80
WIRE -80 208 -80 192
WIRE -80 208 -128 208
WIRE -48 208 -48 192
WIRE 16 208 16 192
WIRE 16 208 -48 208
WIRE 128 208 16 208
WIRE -432 224 -432 192
WIRE -432 224 -464 224
WIRE 96 224 -48 224
WIRE 128 224 128 208
WIRE -480 240 -480 192
WIRE -480 240 -496 240
WIRE -192 240 -192 192
WIRE -192 240 -208 240
WIRE -656 256 -656 -192
WIRE -592 256 -656 256
WIRE -464 256 -464 224
WIRE -464 256 -480 256
WIRE -304 256 -320 256
WIRE -48 256 -48 224
WIRE -16 256 -16 192
WIRE -480 272 -480 256
WIRE -480 272 -496 272
WIRE -160 272 -160 224
WIRE -160 272 -208 272
WIRE -592 288 -624 288
WIRE -432 288 -464 288
WIRE -336 288 -336 144
WIRE -336 288 -352 288
WIRE -304 288 -336 288
WIRE -464 304 -464 288
WIRE -464 304 -496 304
WIRE -176 304 -176 208
WIRE -176 304 -208 304
WIRE -144 304 -176 304
WIRE 160 304 160 80
WIRE 288 304 288 272
WIRE 288 304 160 304
WIRE 288 336 288 304
WIRE -144 352 -144 304
WIRE -80 352 -80 320
WIRE -80 352 -144 352
WIRE -16 352 -16 320
WIRE -16 352 -80 352
WIRE -48 368 -48 320
WIRE -48 368 -64 368
WIRE 16 368 16 320
WIRE 16 368 -48 368
WIRE 96 368 96 224
WIRE 96 368 16 368
WIRE -320 384 -320 256
WIRE -64 384 -64 368
WIRE -624 400 -624 288
WIRE -464 400 -464 304
WIRE -464 400 -624 400
WIRE 288 464 288 416
FLAG 288 464 0
FLAG -64 384 0
FLAG -320 384 0
FLAG -320 96 0
FLAG -528 96 0
FLAG -624 96 0
FLAG 512 80 0
FLAG 624 80 0
FLAG 512 -96 P15
FLAG 624 -96 N15
FLAG 16 128 P15
FLAG 16 256 P15
FLAG -80 256 N15
FLAG -80 128 N15
FLAG -480 192 P15
FLAG -192 192 P15
FLAG 32 -112 P15
FLAG 80 -112 N15
FLAG -160 224 N15
FLAG -432 192 N15
FLAG 128 224 0
SYMBOL AutoGenerated\\AD633 -32 160 R270
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL AutoGenerated\\AD633 -32 288 R270
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL AutoGenerated\\AD711 -544 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName U3
SYMBOL AutoGenerated\\AD711 -256 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName U4
SYMBOL AutoGenerated\\AD711 -32 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName U5
SYMBOL res -448 304 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 176 80 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1.5k
SYMBOL res 272 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 3k
SYMBOL res 272 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 50k
SYMBOL res -496 -64 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 1.98k
SYMBOL cap -544 -32 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 68n
SYMBOL cap -336 -32 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 6.8n
SYMBOL ind -640 -64 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 18m IC = 0.1
SYMBOL res -192 -64 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL res 160 -176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL voltage 512 -64 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 15
SYMBOL voltage 624 -64 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value -15
SYMBOL cap -304 160 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 47n
TEXT 472 192 Left 2 ;711\n13 - Non inverting Input\n15 - Inverting Input\n12 - Positive Supply\n16 - Negative Supply\n14 - Output
TEXT 728 -136 Left 2 ;633\n1 - X1\n2 - X2\n3 - Y1\n4 - Y2\n5 - Vneg\n6 - Z\n7 - W\n8 - Vpos
TEXT -658 488 Left 2 !.tran 0 30s 0 10m uic
```

AD633 and AD711 spice models: http://pastebin.com/3288sPaD

```
* AD711 SPICE Macro-model  
* Description: Amplifier 
* Generic Desc: 10/30V, BIP, OP, Fast, Precision, 1X
* Developed by: JLW / PMI, TRW / ADI
* Revision History: 08/10/2012 - Updated to new header style
* 3.0 (03/1991) - Corrected VOS to be 0.1mV.
* Copyright 1991, 2012 by Analog Devices.
*
* Refer to http://www.analog.com/Analog_Root/static/techSupport/designTools/spiceModels/license/spice_general.html for License Statement. Use of this model
* indicates your acceptance with the terms and provisions in the License Statement.
*
* BEGIN Notes:
*
* Not Modeled:
*
* Parameters modeled include:
* This version of the AD711 model simulates the typical 
* parameters corresponding to the device data sheet.
*
* END Notes
*
* Node assignments
* connections: non-inverting input 
*              |  inverting input  
*              |  |  positive supply
*              |  |  |  negative supply
*              |  |  |  |  output
*              |  |  |  |  |
.SUBCKT AD711 13 15 12 16 14
* 
VOS 15 8 DC 0.1E-3
EC 9 0 (14,0) 1
C1 6 7 .5E-12
RP 16 12 12E3
GB 11 0 (3,0) 1.67E3
RD1 6 16 16E3
RD2 7 16 16E3
ISS 12 1 DC 100E-6
CCI 3 11 150E-12
GCM 0 3 (0,1) 1.76E-9
GA 3 0 (7,6) 2.3E-3
RE 1 0 2.5E6
RGM 3 0 1.69E3
VC 12 2 DC 2.8
VE 10 16 DC 2.8
RO1 11 14 25
CE 1 0 2E-12
RO2 0 11 30
RS1 1 4 5.77E3
RS2 1 5 5.77E3
J1 6 13 4 FET
J2 7 8 5 FET
DC 14 2 DIODE
DE 10 14 DIODE
DP 16 12 DIODE
D1 9 11 DIODE
D2 11 9 DIODE
IOS 15 13 5E-12
.MODEL DIODE D()
.MODEL FET PJF(VTO=-1 BETA=1E-3 IS=15E-12)
.ENDS

* AD633 Analog Multiplier Macro Model 12/93, Rev. A
* AAG/PMI
*
* Copyright 1993 by Analog Devices, Inc.
*
* Refer to "README.DOC" file for License Statement.  Use of this model
* indicates your acceptance with the terms and provisions in the License Statement.
*
* Node assignments
*             X1
*             |  X2
*             |  |  Y1
*             |  |  |  Y2
*             |  |  |  |  VNEG
*             |  |  |  |  |  Z
*             |  |  |  |  |  |  W
*             |  |  |  |  |  |  |  VPOS
*             |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
.SUBCKT AD633 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
*
EREF 100 0 POLY(2) 8 0 5 0 (0,0.5,0.5)
*
* X-INPUT STAGE & POLE AT 15 MHz
*
IBX1 1 0 DC 8E-7
IBX2 2 0 DC 8E-7
EOSX 10 1 POLY(1) (16,100) (5E-3,1)
RX1A 10 11 5E6
RX1B 11 2 5E6
*
GX 100 12 10 2 1E-6
RX 12 100 1E6
CX 12 100 1.061E-14
VX1 8 13 DC 3.05
DX1 12 13 DX
VX2 14 5 DC 3.05
DX2 14 12 DX
*
* COMMON-MODE GAIN NETWORK WITH ZERO AT 560 Hz
*
ECMX 15 100 11 100 10
RCMX1 15 16 1E6
CCMX 15 16 2.8421E-10
RCMX2 16 100 1
*
* Y-INPUT STAGE & POLE AT 15 MHz
*
IBY1 3 0 DC 8E-7
IBY2 4 0 DC 8E-7
EOSY 20 3 POLY(1) (26,100) (5E-3,1)
RY1A 20 21 5E6
RY1B 21 4 5E6
*
GY 100 22 20 4 1E-6
RY 22 100 1E6
CY 22 100 1.061E-14
VY1 8 23 DC 3.05
DY1 22 23 DX
VY2 24 5 DC 3.05
DY2 24 22 DX
*
* COMMON-MODE GAIN NETWORK WITH ZERO AT 560 Hz
*
ECMY 25 100 21 100 10
RCMY1 25 26 1E6
CCMY 25 26 2.8421E-10
RCMY2 26 100 1
*
* Z-INPUT STAGE & POLE AT 15 MHz
*
IBZ1 7 0 DC 8E-7
IBZ2 6 0 DC 8E-7
RZ1 7 6 10E6
*
GZ 100 32 7 6 1E-6
RZ2 32 100 1E6
CZ 32 100 1.061E-14
VZ1 8 33 DC 3.05
DZ1 32 33 DX
VZ2 34 5 DC 3.05
DZ2 34 33 DX
*
* 50-MHz MULTIPLIER CORE & SUMMER
*
GXY 100 40 POLY(2) (12,100) (22,100) (0,0,0,0,0.1E-6)
RXY 40 100 1E6
CXY 40 100 3.1831E-15
*
* OP AMP INPUT STAGE
*
VOOS 59 40 DC 5E-3
Q1 55 32 60 QX
Q2 56 59 61 QX
R1 8 55 3.1831E4
R2 60 54 3.1313E4
R3 8 56 3.1831E4
R4 61 54 3.1313E4
I1 54 5 1E-4
*
* GAIN STAGE & DOMINANT POLE AT 316.23 Hz
*
G1 100 62 55 56 3.141637E-5
R5 62 100 1.0066E8
C3 62 100 5E-12
V1 8 63 DC 4.3399
D1 62 63 DX
V2 64 5 DC 4.3399
D2 64 62 DX
*
* NEGATIVE ZERO AT 20 MHz
*
ENZ 65 100 62 100 1E6
RNZ1 65 66 1
FNZ 65 66 VNC -1
RNZ2 66 100 1E-6
ENC 67 0 65 66 1
CNZ 67 68 7.9577E-9
VNC 68 0 DC 0
*
* POLE AT 4 MHz
*
G2 100 69 66 100 1E-6
R6 69 100 1E6
C2 69 100 3.9789E-14
*
* OP AMP OUTPUT STAGE
*
FSY 8 5 POLY(2) VZC1 VZC2 (2.8286E-3,1,1)
RDC 8 5 28E3
GZC 100 73 72 69 11.623E-3
VZC1 74 100 DC 0
DZC1 73 74 DX
VZC2 100 75 DC 0
DZC2 75 73 DX
VSC1 70 72 0.695
DSC1 69 70 DX
VSC2 72 71 0.695
DSC2 71 69 DX
GO1 72 8 8 69 11.623E-3 
RO1 8 72 86
GO2 5 72 69 5 11.623E-3 
RO2 72 5 86
LO 72 7 1E-7
*
* MODELS USED
*
.MODEL QX NPN(BF=1E4)
.MODEL DX D(IS=1E-15)
.ENDS AD633
```

Comment: At least a schematic, or better yet the actual ltspice file are necessary to be able to experience what you do.

Comment: This is .asc file content: http://pastebin.com/itCNJDMx
Couldn't find how to attach files.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Does nothing?  Goes up in smoke?  Eats your hidden stash of marshmellows?

Comment: The V1-V2 output should look like this: http://jamesnsears.com/archive/chua2scroll1.jpg But my results nowhere near that.

Comment: So, if you can post an image of what you are getting for output, we can put that in and have a complete question.

Comment: "nowhere near that"? What does that mean?

Comment: Well, my output is not even close to expected output. That's why I didn't upload it but, here it is: http://imgur.com/ULPBfeT

Comment: Chua's circuit is, like all chaotic oscillators, a bounded function based on the randomness of system noise.  I made an encryption engine based on two synchronized chaotic oscillators for old analog TV, and I must say that the issues of part mismatch were very real and we swapped and tuned things until they were near enough to see the image. SPICE does not good job with noise.  Regarding the MEMRISTOR, I have an array of these on my desk, and we see a bit of hysteresis between current direction that will not show up in the models.  Even if you sim it, it might not reflect the behavior.

Comment: *"a bounded function based on the randomness of system noise"* I agree that that is not something a circuit simulator like LTspice can simulate.

Answer (score 1):

Chaotic means random, on a bench (real circuit) all components generate **noise** which is **random**. Also in a real circuit, not all components are identical.

In a simulator there is no random noise, you can do a noise simulation but that only predicts the **magnitude** of the noise for a linearized circuit.

What you need is **large signal noise/random behavior** which is simply **not modeled**.

So you will **not** be able to reproduce the behavior you see on the real circuit because that random behavior it is **not modeled** !

Comment: Not actually random. Chaotic Circuit (or Chua's Circuit) is simply a non-periodic oscillator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua's_circuit

Comment: OK, then explain to me **why** this circuit has this non-periodic oscillation behavior. It is because of...

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. The mathematics part is way too complicated for me. But in the Wikipedia page there is the models section and someone explained the modeling parameters and equations there.

Also someone modeled a chaotic circuit here: [link](http://juho-eric.blogspot.com.tr/2011/12/ltspice-simulation-of-chuas-circuit.html) I tried it myself, on LTspice and it worked. So, chaotic behaviour can be modeled.

Comment: I'd say that that is **predictable** chaos and not real chaos. I mean, since there is no statistical variation in the circuit model, it would simulate the same curve for every simulation. The only way you can simulate statistical variations is by using a **Monte Carlo** simulation where component values have statistical variations. So: this is fake chaos, not real chaos, circuit simulators cannot simulate real chaos.